# Bulk load Postgres with unique constraints

Tags: postgresql

I have a large amount of data (100's of GB) that I want to load into Postgres. I have been reading the documentation, where it suggests removing indexes and foreign keys.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html

I want to have some unique constraints on the fields in the table (i.e 3 of the columns are unique together). How do I load this?

I can see some different options:

A) Load it as normal via Python or something similar (slow - to the point that it may not be worth doing).

B) Take of the unique constraint, load the data, reapply the constraint (what happens in this case when there are duplicates?)

C) Load data into temporary table (without unique constraints). Do something clever in the  SQL to remove duplicates, and copy the result into the main table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pg_bulkload load it.
pg_buldload support load data direct and do not need to write shared buffer, and support parallel. so fast than unlogged table.
you can create unique constraint first, and then use pg_bulkload it, pg_bulkload can record the error rows into logfile and correct row load correct. you can deal the error after load.
for exp :

```
wget http://pgfoundry.org/frs/download.php/3566/pg_bulkload-3.1.5.tar.gz
[root@db-172-16-3-150 ~]# export PATH=/home/pg93/pgsql9.3.3/bin:$PATH
[root@db-172-16-3-150 ~]# cd /opt/soft_bak/pg_bulkload-3.1.5
[root@db-172-16-3-150 pg_bulkload-3.1.5]# which pg_config
/home/pg93/pgsql9.3.3/bin/pg_config
[root@db-172-16-3-150 pg_bulkload-3.1.5]# make
[root@db-172-16-3-150 pg_bulkload-3.1.5]# make install

pg93@db-172-16-3-150-> psql
psql (9.3.3)
Type "help" for help.
digoal=# truncate test;
TRUNCATE TABLE
digoal=# create extension pg_bulkload;

pg_bulkload -i /ssd3/pg93/test.dmp -O test -l /ssd3/pg93/test.log -o "TYPE=CSV" -o "WRITER=PARALLEL" -h $PGDATA -p $PGPORT -d $PGDATABASE

[root@db-172-16-3-150 pg93]# cat test.log
pg_bulkload 3.1.5 on 2014-03-28 13:32:31.32559+08

INPUT = /ssd3/pg93/test.dmp
PARSE_BADFILE = /ssd4/pg93/pg_root/pg_bulkload/20140328133231_digoal_public_test.prs.dmp
LOGFILE = /ssd3/pg93/test.log
LIMIT = INFINITE
PARSE_ERRORS = 0
CHECK_CONSTRAINTS = NO
TYPE = CSV
SKIP = 0
DELIMITER = ,
QUOTE = "\""
ESCAPE = "\""
NULL = 
OUTPUT = public.test
MULTI_PROCESS = YES
VERBOSE = NO
WRITER = DIRECT
DUPLICATE_BADFILE = /ssd4/pg93/pg_root/pg_bulkload/20140328133231_digoal_public_test.dup.csv
DUPLICATE_ERRORS = 0
ON_DUPLICATE_KEEP = NEW
TRUNCATE = NO


  0 Rows skipped.
  50000000 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to parse errors.
  0 Rows not loaded due to duplicate errors.
  0 Rows replaced with new rows.

Run began on 2014-03-28 13:32:31.32559+08
Run ended on 2014-03-28 13:35:13.019018+08

CPU 1.55s/128.55u sec elapsed 161.69 sec
```